# Does the series $\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{j}{\sqrt[3]{8 j^5-1}}$ Converge?II

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate numerically the following series$$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{j}{\sqrt[3]{8 j^5-1}}$$, I know that it is divergent, although using analytical continuation it can be sum using Euler Maclaurin, we obtain$$\int_1^n \frac{j}{\sqrt[3]{8 j^5-1}} \, dj-\frac{10 n^5}{9 \left(8 n^5-1\right)^{4/3}}+\frac{n}{2 \sqrt[3]{8 n^5-1}}+\frac{1}{12 \sqrt[3]{8 n^5-1}}+\frac{22400 n^{13}}{243 \left(8 n^5-1\right)^{10/3}}-\frac{400 n^8}{27 \left(8 n^5-1\right)^{7/3}}+\frac{4 n^3}{9 \left(8 n^5-1\right)^{4/3}}$$ as $$n\to \infty$$
but numerically nothing significant is obtained because the integral does not converge, you could check if the following value is correct $$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \frac{j}{\sqrt[3]{8 j^5-1}}\simeq -1.20056811100537966552663$$
calculating the integral using Mathematica$$\frac{1}{2} \left(7^{2/3} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{16}{15};\frac{7}{5};8\right)-n^2 \left(8 n^5-1\right)^{2/3} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{16}{15};\frac{7}{5};8 n^5\right)\right)-\frac{10 n^5}{9 \left(8 n^5-1\right)^{4/3}}+\frac{n}{2 \sqrt[3]{8 n^5-1}}+\frac{1}{12 \sqrt[3]{8 n^5-1}}+\frac{22400 n^{13}}{243 \left(8 n^5-1\right)^{10/3}}-\frac{400 n^8}{27 \left(8 n^5-1\right)^{7/3}}+\frac{4 n^3}{9 \left(8 n^5-1\right)^{4/3}}$$ but no consistent results are obtained for different values ​​of n

Comment: How are you getting a negative value?

Comment: $$\frac{j}{\sqrt[3]{8j^5-1}}\sim \frac1{2j^{2/3}}$$

Comment: The series doesn't converge, even if it has a Ramanujan sum. I'm not sure what you mean by "I know it divergent, but by analytic continuation it can be sum by Euler Maclaurin." If I'm reading that correctly, you are not talking about convergence of the sum, but a different kind of summability of a series like the Ramanujan sum of $1+2+3+\dots.$ These sums are not convergent sums, but a different kind of sum entirely, that you have to be very careful with.

Comment: @Thomas Andrew I am happy to hear a numericaly answer using eulermaclaurin formula.

Comment: The only question in this post is in the the title, and the answer is no, the series doesn't converge. If you intended to ask a different question, please clarify that.

Comment: There are many ways to define the "sum" of a divergent series, but it sounds like you're interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) one.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews as you know $$\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{2}=-1.22379$$

Comment: So? What does that have to do with convergence of a series. Convergence means something specific. This series does not converge, and the series for $\zeta(2/3)$ doesn't converge, either. You asked about convergence, quite explicitly, and the series does not converge. @Capeamate

Comment: you ask How are you getting a negative value? so it is coherent with the result.